# options for Healthcare and benefits for recently graduated PhD who is short-term unemployed?

Tags: united-states, health-insurance, healthcare, benefits, unemployment

I recently (2015) graduated from a PhD program in a very employable science/engineering major from a top three university in the United States. Due to some health and motivational issues (ones that most people would consider to be minor and that most likely cannot be used for any sort of disability claim), I have not lined up a full time position after graduation. However, I have recently worked out these issues, and will not have any problems finding a full time position within the next two months.

Meanwhile, in the short term, I would like to know what my options are in terms of healthcare coverage (I am currently covered by my school's plan as a postdoc, which runs out in a few days. COBRA is too expensive so is out of the question). The consensus seems to be healthcare.gov, so I am pursuing that. However, I have never been in a situation where I have had to shop for my own health insurance before, so I have no idea how much of this works.

Are there any obvious benefits or exceptions I can claim as someone who is technically unemployed, both for healthcare, and in general? Does the fact that my period of unemployment will only be short-term (less than two or three months, in all likelihood) make it impractical and not worth the effort to apply for benefits for unemployed people, even if I qualify for them? Will receiving unemployment benefits hurt my credit or anything to that effect in any way?

Comment: The answers to these questions will vary widely by state.

Comment: Some university alumni associations have health insurance options for new graduates. If they have it, you might compare the costs with ACA options. You might also be eligible for COBRA coverage.

Comment: COBRA in my school's case is too expensive. Almost $700 a month. I recently moved to NYC.

Comment: I think you'll find that all healthcare in NYC is expensive thanks to a regulation disallowing the age rating of premiums.  Though with no income you'll probably qualify in to Medicaid at no cost.